# Change the size and position of texts

Tags: css

I want to make some changes to some plugin parameters.  No coding needed.  It's all about adjusting the font size and text position...

I'm looking for a simple way to change the font and text size for some html titles, how is that?

Comment: https://web.dev/learn/css/

Answer (score 0):

<(anyhtmltag) style="font-size: 2(px/em/etc)">Text<(anyhtmlclosingtag)>

Alternatively you can add classes

```css
.title {
  font-size: 3em;
  font-weight: 600;
 }
 
 .para {
  font-size: 2.2em;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
  <p class="para">text</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, you have benefited a lot

Comment: Please, how do I locate the text?

Comment: By locate do you mean to position somewhere?

Comment: No no thank you, this is what I want